# How can I copy and paste conditional formatting over a range of cells, and include an offset so the reference values change as well?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, copy-paste

Afternoon,

on whatever version of excel comes with Office365

Basically I need to format a cell based on if the other cell has data. I have used the =not(isblank(b1)) in conditional formatting to turn a2+a3 red. This all works fine. Now I need to copy that conditional formatting rule and apply it across the rows, so it would be b3 as the next cell affecting a4+a5 and so on...

I can do this manually but it is for a rota and that is... a lot of manual work!

If there is a way to apply this worksheet wide? Or a script that can take that conditional formatting, apply an offset, and write it on the next set of cells?

Thanks!

*EDIT* using the autofill bottom right cross, I set the formula in the first block then copied it over the other blocks and that worked fine, just a bit tedious!

Comment: Edit the condition and change the range is applies to?

Comment: I tried that, but it needs to apply to 3 cell blocks across the whole row and I can only get the whole row to change instead of the blocks

Comment: Can you upload of a screencap of your condition (and the cells it applies to) to http://imgur.som and link to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formulas to define formatting rules.
My proposal is in two versions:

- with 2 rules (the same formula, but for different scopes)

  `=(B1<>"")*MOD(ROW(B1),2)`

Scopes, e.g., `$A$2:$A$24` and `$A$3:$A$25`

- with a single rule

`=OFFSET(H2,-1-MOD(ROW(H2),2),1)<>""`

You can easily extend scopes if required.
[image: Conditional format example]